# HP Fortify - Dead Code stored in Asp.net Temp Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

Is there a possible fix for Dead Code identified by Fortify when scanning an Asp.net MVC 3 project? The code identified as "dead' is in a generated files, stored in the Asp.net temp files folder. We have 173 of these findings showing up in our scan results. We are using version 6.10 of the HP Fortify scanner, with the latest rulepacks.

Comment: There really isn't much you can or should worry about with stuff created in a Temp folder OR in generated files.  Can you set Fortify to ignore it in some way?  if it's in a certain folder or contains certain text?

Comment: Our IA team marks these issues as low priority, but it is frustrating having these show up in our scan results. There must be some way to actually mitigate these findings correctly.

Comment: The only way to "mitigate" a dead code finding is to call the code. If Fortify sees the code being executed, it won't flag it. The main reason why Fortify flags dead code is that it makes it harder to maintain a code base, which can affect the overall security of the application. Since these are generated files, you're not maintaining them. You either need to exclude them from the scan or make the case to your IA team that it's not a finding and suppress them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an article that actually mitigates the Fortify dead code in MVC. Appearantly, out of the box Fortify scans the the MVC website as if it is a standard ASP.net application.

Modify fortify properties file

Open up {Fortify_install_dir}\Core\config\fortify.properties and uncomment the following:

com.fortify.VS.SkipASPPrecompilation=true
and also, set the following property to false (Default value is true).

com.fortify.VS.RequireASPPrecompilation=false
Build your project

Build your project as normal in Visual studio

Copy build artifacts

Copy the build artifacts from the /bin directory at the root of your project to the following location -

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{frameworkverion}\Temporary ASP.NET Files{yourprojectname}
So for a project named “YourProject.Web” that build against .NET 4 or 4.5, the path would look like this-

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\YourProject.Web
Run the scan

See the full article by Charles King here:

http://charlesbking.com/programming/2015/01/23/run-fortify-on-asp-mvc.html

Comment: Be careful with those two properties. If you turn those off to scan an MVC app, but then go and scan a web form app, it will miss A LOT of code. I'm not a .NET MVC expert, but I don't think you need to do this in order to scan MVC. If there are no ASPX pages in your MVC app, then the precompile step won't do anything. Fortify will then just scan the compiled DLL files with PDBs. Scanning a web form, MVC, or API should be as easy as using the Scan Solution option in the Visual Studio plugin or by invoking the Fortify CLI like: sourceanalyzer -b mybuild devenv myproj.sln /REBUILD DEBUG